# Run this monadic computation with notion of state and randomness

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, io-monad

I describe the following computation:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Random.Class

-- * fair coin
fair :: MonadRandom m => m Bool
fair = (\p -> p <= 0.5) <$> getRandomR (0,1 :: Double)

-- * how do i run this 
bar :: (MonadState Bool m, MonadRandom m) => m Bool
bar = fair >>= \b -> put b >> return b
```

And I would like to know how to run `bar` so that in expectation, `bar` evaluates to `True` half of the time.

Comment: I don't understand. What happens now?

Comment: @Michael: They’ve written some code using monad transformers without the stack explicitly specified, and they’re asking how to construct and run a stack of monad transformers to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

```
evalRandIO $ evalStateT bar False
```

Let’s pick this apart. `bar` needs to be able to maintain a `Bool` as a state, and be able to get random values. We could nest it either way; here, I chose to layer the state atop the random, but you could do it the other way around.

`evalStateT` has this type signature:

```
evalStateT :: Monad m => StateT s m a -> s -> m a
```

In words, given something that needs a state layered atop some other monad, it implements that state part and gives you that action in terms of the underlying monad. The `eval` part of the name means that it will throw out the resulting state and give you just the value; there is also `execStateT` that gives you the resulting state and throws out the output, and `runStateT` that gives you a tuple of both. I should note that in any case, we have to give it an initial state. Your code doesn’t use the initial state, so we could just as well have used `undefined`, but I used `False` for the heck of it.

So now that we’ve implemented the state bit, what do we have left?

```
ghci> :t evalStateT bar False
evalStateT bar False :: MonadRandom m => m Bool
```

It wants a monad that can give it random values. Well, we have one of those. `Rand` will do it. `Rand`, too, has `run`, `eval`, and `exec` variants, since it’s actually a state monad too; it holds a value of some type of class `RandomGen` under the covers. Here, we *don’t* want to discard the state at the end, and we *do* want to keep the result, too, so we use the `run` variant. Well, what do we have now?

```
ghci> :t runRand (evalStateT bar False)
runRand (evalStateT bar False) :: RandomGen g => g -> (Bool, g)
```

For comparison:

```
ghci> :t random
random :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> (a, g)
```

So now we have a plain function that takes a random-number generator state and spits out a pair with a result and a new state, just like `random` itself from `System.Random`. How can we use this? Well, digging through the `System.Random` module, `getStdRandom` looks useful:

```
getStdRandom :: (StdGen -> (a, StdGen)) -> IO a
```

It takes a function like the one we have and turns it into an `IO` action.  (This makes sense that it would be `IO`; it’s taking some global state (namely, the standard random number generator) and updating it.)  What do we have after tacking that on?

```
ghci> :t getStdRandom . runRand $ evalStateT bar False
getStdRandom . runRand $ evalStateT bar False :: IO Bool
```

Exactly what we expect: an `IO` that yields a `Bool`.  Run it a few times:

```
ghci> let barIO = getStdRandom . runRand $ evalStateT bar False
ghci> barIO
True
ghci> barIO
True
ghci> barIO
False
```

Random enough for me.  However, [as Carsten mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327146/run-this-monadic-computation-with-notion-of-state-and-randomness/34327381?noredirect=1#comment56396553_34327381), there’s a shorter way.  Since this is such a common use-case, the `Control.Monad.Random` module provides a shortcut, `evalRandIO`, which is essentially the `getStdRandom . runRand` we used above.  It’s a simple replacement to end up with

```
evalRandIO $ evalStateT bar False
```

Comment: great answer - you can shorten the last part a bit using `evalRandIO` as should  `evalRandIO $ evalStateT bar False` work as well